# Need help in validating 50 fields in JSON

Tags: json

I have a JSON file with almost 50 fields in it and I need to validate each one of them through automation. Also I have the test data for all 50 fields to be validated in an excel sheet.

The logic I am stuck here is I cannot place all 50 field's data in the excel cells since it will make my sheet look bulk. Any suggestions on how I can validate this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use Python/Java/C# etc to directly read the excel sheet (or export the excel sheet to a CSV file) then write code to validate the JSON against the read data?  You don't have to put the validation result back into the excel sheet, do you?